# How to create google map tooltip in marker using @react-google-maps/api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-maps

I want to create a tool-tip on a marker on the map, that when clicked opens a window with some information. I use @react-google-maps/api

I want something like this:
[image]

this is my code:

```js
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript, Marker } from '@react-google-maps/api';
import { AppConfig } from '../../../constants/AppConfig';

const containerStyle = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
};

export interface MapProps {
  isMarkerShown?: boolean;
  otherMarkers?: {
    lat: number;
    lng: number;
  }[];
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
}

export const Map = ({ lat, lng, isMarkerShown = true, otherMarkers }: MapProps) => {
  return (
    <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey={AppConfig.googleMapsApiKey}>
      <GoogleMap
        options={{
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          styles: [
            { featureType: 'poi', elementType: 'labels', stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }] },
            { featureType: 'transit', elementType: 'labels', stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }] },
          ],
        }}
        mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
        center={{ lat, lng }}
        zoom={15}
      >
        <Marker
          position={{ lat, lng }}
          visible={isMarkerShown}
          options={{}}
          icon="/assets/svg/MapMakerIcon.svg"
        />
        {/* other markers */}
        {otherMarkers &&
          otherMarkers.map((marker) => (
            <Marker
              title="marker"
              key={`${marker.lat}-${marker.lng}`}
              position={{ lat: marker.lat, lng: marker.lng }}
              icon="/assets/svg/MapMarkerRoundedIcon.svg"
            />
          ))}
      </GoogleMap>
    </LoadScript>
  );
};
```

I want render the tooltip in other markers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a tooltip-like pop-up on a marker in your Google Map using `@react-google-maps/api`.

`@react-google-maps/api` has a component called InfoBox that can be used to display information

A state must be created to save information about some data and to verify that it is open.

A function must be defined to manage the clinics in the markers and update the status with the information of the selected marker.

And customize the content of the `InfoBox` to display the desired information.

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript, Marker, InfoBox } from '@react-google-maps/api';
import { Box, Typography } from '@mui/material';

import { AppConfig } from '../../../constants/AppConfig';
import { Color } from '../../../theme/MUITheme/colors';
import CloseIcon from '../../icons/CloseIcon';
import { IconButton } from '../IconButton/IconButton';
import { VSpacer } from '../Spacer';
import { TextLink } from '../TextLink/TextLink';
import DirectionsIcon from '../../icons/DirectionsIcon';

import './Map.scss';
import { IClinicInformation } from '@libs/shared';

const containerStyle = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
};

export interface MapProps {
  isMarkerShown?: boolean;
  clinicsInformation?: IClinicInformation[];
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
}

export const Map = ({ lat, lng, isMarkerShown = true, clinicsInformation }: MapProps) => {
  const [selectedClinic, setSelectedClinic] = useState<IClinicInformation | null>(null);

  const handleMarkerClick = (marker: IClinicInformation) => {
    setSelectedClinic(marker);
  };

  return (
    <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey={AppConfig.googleMapsApiKey}>
      <GoogleMap
        options={{
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          styles: [
            { featureType: 'poi', elementType: 'labels', stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }] },
            { featureType: 'transit', elementType: 'labels', stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }] },
          ],
        }}
        mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
        center={{ lat, lng }}
        zoom={15}
      >
        <Marker
          position={{ lat, lng }}
          visible={isMarkerShown}
          icon="/assets/svg/MapMakerIcon.svg"
        />
        {/* other markers */}
        {clinicsInformation &&
          clinicsInformation.map((clinic) => (
            <Marker
              title="marker"
              key={`${clinic.location?.coordinates[0]}-${clinic.location?.coordinates[1]}`}
              position={{
                lat: clinic.location?.coordinates[0] ?? 0,
                lng: clinic.location?.coordinates[1] ?? 0,
              }}
              icon="/assets/svg/MapMarkerRoundedIcon.svg"
              onClick={() => handleMarkerClick(clinic)}
            />
          ))}
        {selectedClinic && (
          <InfoBox
            position={
              new google.maps.LatLng(
                selectedClinic.location?.coordinates[0] ?? 0,
                selectedClinic.location?.coordinates[1] ?? 0,
              )
            }
            options={{
              closeBoxURL: '',
              enableEventPropagation: true,
            }}
          >
            <Box
              borderRadius="10px"
              boxShadow="0px 4px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)"
              padding="9px 13px"
              width="100%"
              sx={{ backgroundColor: '#fff' }}
            >
              <Box display="flex" alignItems="center" justifyContent="space-between">
                <Typography color={Color.primary.main} variant="body2" fontWeight="bold">
                  {selectedClinic.name}
                </Typography>
                <IconButton
                  testID="close-tooltip"
                  size="small"
                  onClick={() => setSelectedClinic(null)}
                  sx={{ padding: '4px' }}
                >
                  <CloseIcon />
                </IconButton>
              </Box>

              <VSpacer size="1" />

              <Box display="flex" alignItems="start" justifyContent="space-between">
                <Box>
                  <Typography fontSize="12px" variant="body2">
                    {selectedClinic.address?.main}
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography fontSize="12px" variant="body2">
                    Abierto {selectedClinic.is24Hours ? '24 horas' : 'hasta las 18:00'}
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography noWrap fontSize="12px" variant="body2">
                    Teléfono: {selectedClinic.directPhone}
                  </Typography>
                  <TextLink fontSize="12px" testID="view-more">
                    Ver más
                  </TextLink>
                </Box>
                <IconButton testID="directions" size="small" sx={{ padding: '4px' }}>
                  <DirectionsIcon />
                </IconButton>
              </Box>
            </Box>
          </InfoBox>
        )}
      </GoogleMap>
    </LoadScript>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to go read the documentation and found out that there were some missing parts. You can consider

That, you only need to add a Child Component that takes 'lat' and 'lng' Props. And that Component should returns a text, image and your marker.

Comment: I use the interface on my code, there has no relation with my problem